# What is rate limiting for android app shortcuts?

Tags: android, android-7.1-nougat, android-appshortcut

As per documentation for app shortcuts

> **Rate Limiting**
>   When using the setDynamicShortcuts(), addDynamicShortcuts(), or
>   updateShortcuts() methods, keep in mind that you might only be able to
>   call these methods a specific number of times in a background app, an
>   app with no activities or services currently in the foreground. In a
>   production environment, you can reset this rate limiting by bringing
>   your app to the foreground.

What is rate limiting in concern with app shortcuts? when **isRateLimitingActive()** should be used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Looking at the source code it seems that the `isRateLimitingActive()` method returns false if you do not have any remaining calls left to the `ShortcutManager` API *(hence the "0")*. I guess rate limiting is needed because the API is resource intensive. I can imagine that at least the following will happen if you update a shortcut:

   - The launcher app (and other listeners) needs to be notified and starts updating it's UI or whatever is needed (depends on the launcher);
   - The system needs to [store](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/90e5fc097070aa5170f2e5fd6def1461e96928f2/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/ShortcutService.java#L1700) the new dynamic shortcut information;
2. You could use this method to find out if a call to `setDynamicShortcuts()`, `addDynamicShortcuts()` or `updateShortcuts()` will succeed before even trying to do so.

**[Source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/82834baa358f55acb542e17da828b2d497cf8332/core/java/android/content/pm/ShortcutManager.java#L738):**

```
/**
 * Return {@code true} when rate-limiting is active for the caller application.
 *
 * <p>See the class level javadoc for details.
 *
 * @throws IllegalStateException when the user is locked.
 */
public boolean isRateLimitingActive() {
    try {
        return mService.getRemainingCallCount(mContext.getPackageName(), injectMyUserId())
                == 0;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        throw e.rethrowFromSystemServer();
    }
}
```

> **Bonus:** `setDynamicShortcuts()`, `addDynamicShortcuts()` or `updateShortcuts()` return false if they did not succeed due to Rate Limiting.

Answer (score -1):

The recommended maximum number of shortcuts is 4, although it is possible to publish up to 5. You can read more [here](https://www.developerlibs.com/2017/03/app-shortcuts-android-nougat-71-feature.html).

Comment: Link is dead, so this answer is not very useful any more.

Comment: checkout it here https://www.developerlibs.com/2017/03/app-shortcuts-android-nougat-71-feature.html